# JQuery Show/Hide a text column in a ASP Gridview control

Tags: jquery, gridview

I would appreciate any help and or suggestion that you all can give me. I am not 
sure that I am going about this in the right way, but here is my requirement:

I have a asp:gridview that might have an extended amount of test in a column 
field in each row. There will not any editing of the data in the gridview.

I am trying to show only the first 130 characters of text with a "....[More]" at 
the end of the text. When the user clicks on the [More], a `<div>` scrolls open 
and the short line of text is hidden, the entire amount of text in displayed and 
the [More] text changes to [Less]. When you click on the [Less] the `<div>` closes 
up and the text changes back to [More]. I have the short version and 
the long version of the text loading in to template fields.

Problem: I need to hide the `<asp:Label class="faq_submain">` and the 
`<span class="MemoDataMoreBtn">` after the jQuery function slideDown() finishes, and 
show() them when the slideUp() finishes. I also need to hide the [More] link if the
Eval("MemoText") lengh is less than or equal to zero.

Below is the code for the gridview `<itemtemplate>`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="GridMemo" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #9DC2FF;">
                <asp:Label class="faq_submain" ID="ShortMemoTextLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# LimitTextLine(Eval("MemoText"), 130)%>'></asp:Label>
                <span class="MemoDataMoreBtn">[More]</span>
                <div class="memodatadiv" style="display: none;">
                    <asp:Label ID="LongMemoTextLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MemoText")%>'></asp:Label>
                    <span class="MemoDataLessBtn">[Less]</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the jquery that I am currently using.

```
$(".MemoDataMoreBtn").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".memodatadiv").slideDown(100);
    $(this).prev(".faq_submain").hide();
});
$(".MemoDataLessBtn").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".memodatadiv").slideUp(100);
    $(this).parent("td").after(".faq_submain").show();
});
```

This is how to looks normanally:

[image: Normal]

Problem #1, I hit the [More], the highlited [More] needs to be hidden.
[image: Problem #1]

Problem #2, After I hit the [Less], I need to display the orginal text and the [More] link.
[image: Problem #2]

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is NOT working?

Comment: Do not set style property for the element `style="display: none;"` . The div might never show because of precedence sometimes. Try applying a class for it instead

Comment: The label for the More and the span used are not hidding correctly. The style="display: none" is taken care of via the jQuery.

Comment: @David C - Since I don’t post on here very much, this is my second post, Is there a reason that I haven't even got one possible answer or suggestion on this problem?